# Newton Interpolation in C++

Tags: c++

I had to write Newton Interpolation in C++, but I have some problems...
In addition I had to use function which returns array and I couldn't use two-dimensional arrays.
It's my code:

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void interpol(double *, double *, int, int);
double *countDivide(double *y, double *x, int n);

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Give ammount of nodes: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    double arg;
    double *x = new double[n];
    double *y = new double[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "x[" << i << "] = ";
        cin >> x[i];
        cout << "y[" << i << "] = ";
        cin >> y[i];
    }

    cout << "Give arg: ";
    cin >> arg;
    double* b = countDivide(y, x, n);
    interpol(b, x, n, arg);

    return 0;
}

double *countDivide(double *y, double *x, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    double z;
    for (i = 0; i < n; j++)
    {
        z = y[0];
        for (j = 0 ; j > n - i; j++)
        {
            y[j] = (y[j] - y[j - 1]) / (x[i + j] - x[j]);
        }
        y[n - i] = z;
    }

    return y;
}

void interpol(double *p, double *x, int n, int arg)
{
    double w;
    double sum = 0;
    int j, i;
    for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        w = 1;
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
            w*= (arg - x[j]);

        w *= p[j];
        sum += w;
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
}
```

But program is stopping after

```
cin >> arg
```

What's wrong? I don't know what is wrong with that code, because I spent much time on it...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: hint: what happens to index of `y[j - 1]` when `j = 0` in countDivide ?

Comment: *In addition I had to use function which returns array* -- None of your functions returns an array.  A pointer is not an array.  If you actually did use `std::array` or `std::vector`, the problem would have been discovered using `at()` instead of `[ ]` to access the elements.

Comment: @AhmedMasud I see, so I just have to change `j - 1` to `j` and `j` to `j+1`?
@PaulMcKenzie I said it wrong, I have to return a pointer to an array.

Comment: @AhmedMasud -- `so I just have to change j - 1 to j and j to j+1` -- You're supposed to understand your own program.  Will that change produce incorrect results?  You're supposed to determine that -- what is obvious is that `j - 1` becomes negative on the first iteration, which is an out-of-bounds access.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad.. Forgot about others `j`.

Comment: As @PaulMcKenzie said you have to understand the intent of your program. Can you describe your program to yourself in simple english? (not meant to be an insult, I actually mean that).  If you cannot, encoding it in C++ will be a difficult exercise.

Comment: @AhmedMasud Yep, I can do it, I know how to count it on piece of paper.

Comment: Great! let's go over the code step by step then

Answer (score 2):

This loop doesnt look right

```
for (i = 0; i < n; j++)
```

Comment: Haha, thank you... Now it works, I'm blind, but my result isn't right.